# Narrow sample space down with Google Forms evaluation

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I got the results from a survey I did with Google Forms. The survey results are stored in a Google Spreadsheet (150 rows).

I really like the feature to get the results in diagrams automatically, but I wonder if there is a way to narrow down the sample space?

For example, each participant selected an age group (<18, 18-25, ..), now I just want to see the statistics of the answers of a certain group. Is that possible with the given tools from Google?